# Colorpicker only picks black

Tags: linux, arch-linux, intel-graphics

I have a fresh install of Arch Linux with Gnome and GDM; I use integrated video card: Intel® HD Graphics 630.

Previously I had Fedora installed, and the old rig had an old NVidia GPU. I used a program named "gpick" to pick a color from the screen:

[image: gpick working]

It was working as it should, but with the new rig it's always picking black color:

[image: gpick picks only black color]

I tried to boot Kali Linux and install gpick there. That worked even though the resolution wasn't the native fullHD. I tried gcolor2 which is a similar tool, but it does the same.

I have the following packages installed: `xf86-video-intel` `mesa-libgl` `lib32-mesa-libgl`

How can I fix the picker?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're using GNOME 3 on Fedora with a non-NVidia graphics card, so you're most likely running Wayland as the graphics system. gpick is based on GTK+ 2.x, which only supports X11 and goes through the Xwayland compatibility layer.

So there are two reasons for your problem:

1. The Wayland graphics system *by design* does not allow one program to see the contents of other programs. Features like screenshots or color pickers would therefore need cooperation by the window manager. (For example, the app would ask the WM to take a screenshot and pick colors from *that* instead of the actual screen.)
2. Xwayland acts as a completely separate X11 "display"; while it has hooks allowing individual windows to be interleaved with native ones, and to transfer clipboard contents back & forth, it doesn't pass any other information about Wayland to the X11 apps. As far as those are concerned, they're running on a black desktop with no Wayland in sight.

As a result, gpick can see only other X11 windows, but not native Wayland windows.

You can switch between GNOME+Wayland and GNOME+X11 sessions using the 'gear' icon in GDM's login screen.

Comment: So probably there is nothing wrong with my video card driver right? I just have to wait / search for a colorpicker what is using GTK 3?

Comment: That, or switch back to X11-only mode. Look for the 'gear' button in the GDM login screen.